Does current mode control for dc/dc conv imply a constant current output?
I am getting very confused, I have read articles about current mode and voltage mode control, and it seems that most converters use current mode control - which seems has two nested control loops. The fast inner loop controls the inductor current and the slower outer loop controls the voltage by adjusting the setpoint of the inner loop.
Does it mean that most of these boost converters output a constant current irrespective of the load?
There's a constant frequency, current mode boost converter that I have come across, unsure of they output constant current though. See below:

SDB628

The main reason for this confusion, is that if you look at the datasheet, under application information page 6, it shows calculations to set the output voltage?? Why? Then what's the point of the current sense.
What am I misunderstanding?

No - in most cases they are constant voltage output. As you say in the question there is an outer loop controlling the voltage. One application however of constant current output is for LED drivers.

If you look at the diagram on the first page, the feedback node is hooked up to a voltage divider, so it is regulating output voltage rather than current.  A constant current source would require the feedback be hooked up to a current sense resistor or similar way of measuring current.

@user1850479 so would switching the voltage divider with a current sense (and amp) make it a constant current circuit then?

Yes (although you probably don't need an amp), and in some regulator datasheet (e.g. 7805) that will actually be one of the application examples.
